# How can I get the length of a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have an array as follows:

```
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems').push([[],[],[]]);
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[0][0]['ProductNR'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[0][0]['Title'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[0][0]['Description'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems').push([[],[],[]]);

//-------------------------------------------------
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[1][0]['ProductNR'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[1][0]['Title'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[1][0]['Description'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems').push([[],[],[]]);

//-------------------------------------------------
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[2][0]['ProductNR'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[2][0]['Title'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[2][0]['Description'] = 1;

alert( $('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[0][0].length ); 
// Results --> 3

//-------------------------------------------------
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems').push([[],[],[]]);
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[0][1]['ProductNR'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[0][1]['Title'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[0][1]['Description'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems').push([[],[],[]]);

//-------------------------------------------------
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[1][1]['ProductNR'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[1][1]['Title'] = 1;
$('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[1][1]['Description'] = 1;

alert( $('#MMTable').data('arMSItems').length );
// Results --> 5

//----------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get the number of elements in second field?
E.g. :

```
[0][1]['ProductNR']
[1][1]['ProductNR']
```

I expect a result as 2-elements. But how can I get it?

E.g. the second field is a "1" as follows: [x][1][x]

```
alert( $('#MMTable').data('arMSItems')[x][1][x].length );
```

How many elements does the array contain (I expect a result as 2) ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Logically your array should look like,

```
['arMSItems']['ProductNR'][0]
['arMSItems']['Title'][0]
['arMSItems']['Description'][0]

['arMSItems']['ProductNR'][1]
['arMSItems']['Title'][1]
['arMSItems']['Description'][1]
// so on..
```

Then you can get the length by using,

```
alert(arr['arMSItems']['ProductNR'].length);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/XxaPK/)**